# Json framework of Play

Tags: json, playframework

I am new to Play and Json framework of Play, i am reading https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson,

A quick question hits me is that when we serialize an object of a case class into JSON string, should we have to define the `implicit writers`?

Java world's json framework,like Gson,Jackson can use reflection to serialize an object into json string automatically.

Can't Play use similar reflection things to directly serialize an object into JSON string

Comment: are you looking for something different than Play Automated Mapping?
 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#json-automated-mapping

Comment: Thanks @tgk for the answer, it is what i am after.